# Make ActionLink to specific user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

How do I make the links on the site lead to the current user's page(s)? I dont want them to get lists of every user but only themselves. I'm thinking something like this for my menu links:

@Html.ActionLink("My Details", "Details", "Customers", Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better if you send user to "My Details" page **without any parameter or route values**.

The page is going to show current users data. So why to pass it like this?

Just **Redirect user to "My Detail" page**, and after that, **when user is in that page**, you can get current user using: HttpContext.CurrentUser.

***Don't put user data in route values.*** Instead you can get it in that page's controller and pass it to the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the "Links" to display to show when the page is viewed by an authenticated user, create a ChildAction that returns the data you want like:

```
    [Authorize]
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult UserLinks() {
        var items = someRepository.GetLinks(User.Identity.Name);
        return PartialView(items,"SomePartialView");
    }
```

Then, use the RenderAction in the view like so:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("UserLinks");}
```

Secondly, I agree with the comment by "Afshin Gh". Rather than passing data in your "ActionLink(s)", you could code it in your Controller to filter the data as required - like I'm showing in the "UserLinks" method above. This way, someone can't just manipulate the Url to display data for another customer.